# Sound Card HP Beats Edition ENVY 14 - Codec: IDT 92HD81B1X5

Tags: pulseaudio, intel, alsa, soundcard

I've been trying to put 8 channels working on ubuntu since the 11.10 (I'm now with the 12.04) but with no luck. I only get 2 channels working.

I've tried many internet posts but with no luck.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

I've added in /etc/modprobe.d/:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

and I tried with other models (because I can find the right one to my sound card) and only get 2 channels working.

When I run gnome-alsamixer it only give me access to Intel CougarPoint HDMI sound card not to: IDT 92HD81B1X5

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Hardware info:

```
root@beatsaudio:/home/edup# lspci |grep Audio
<code>
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
</code>

root@beatsaudio:/home/edup# lshw -c multimedia
<code>
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:55 memory:c9700000-c9703fff
</code>

root@beatsaudio:/home/edup# cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* |grep Codec
<code>
Codec: IDT 92HD81B1X5
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
</code>

root@beatsaudio:/home/edup# aplay -l
<code>
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
</code>


root@beatsaudio:/home/edup# cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* 
<code>
Codec: IDT 92HD81B1X5
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x111d7605
Subsystem Id: 0x103c3385
Revision Id: 0x100105
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
Default Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x7f, nsteps=0x7f, stepsize=0x02, mute=1
GPIO: io=3, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=1
  IO[0]: enable=1, dir=1, wake=0, sticky=0, data=1, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Power-Map: 0x02
Node 0x0a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400583: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Jack Mode", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=0, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Amp-In caps: N/A
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001173c: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x03a12020: [Jack] Mic at Ext Left
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Grey
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13* 0x14 0x1c
Node 0x0b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Headphone Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x0001001c: OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x0321201f: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Left
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Grey
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0xf
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13 0x14* 0x1c
Node 0x0c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400583: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: N/A
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00011734: IN OUT EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x40f000f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13* 0x14 0x1c
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400501: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00010050: OUT EAPD Balanced
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13* 0x14 0x1c
Node 0x0e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400583: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: N/A
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00010034: IN OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x40f000f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13* 0x14 0x1c
Node 0x0f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400583: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: N/A
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00010034: IN OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x40f000f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13* 0x14 0x1c
Node 0x10 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400500: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x40f000f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1a
Node 0x11 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400483: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: N/A
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0xd5a30130: [Both] Mic at Int Top
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00503: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: N/A
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x20
Node 0x13 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xd0c05: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=63
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="STAC92xx Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: N/A
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x74 0x74]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 13 samples
Node 0x14 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xd0c05: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=63
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: N/A
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x74 0x74]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 13 samples
Node 0x15 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x1d0541: Stereo
  Device: name="STAC92xx Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Converter: stream=4, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 13 samples
  Connection: 1
     0x17
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=0
Node 0x16 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x1d0541: Stereo
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 13 samples
  Connection: 1
     0x18
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=0
Node 0x17 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300d0d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x0f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x03]
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 7
     0x0c 0x0e 0x0f 0x1b 0x11* 0x12 0x0a
Node 0x18 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300d0d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x0f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 7
     0x0c* 0x0e 0x0f 0x1b 0x11 0x12 0x0a
Node 0x19 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300501: Stereo
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x13* 0x14 0x1c
Node 0x1a [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x200500: Mono
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x19
Node 0x1b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x97 0x97] [0x97 0x97] [0x97 0x97] [0x97 0x97] [0x97 0x97] [0x97 0x97]
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 6
     0x0c 0x0e 0x0f 0x13 0x14 0x0a
Node 0x1c [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x1f, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x9f 0x9f]
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1b
Node 0x1d [Audio Output] wcaps 0x4061d: Stereo Digital Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 4 samples
Node 0x1e [Audio Output] wcaps 0x4061d: Stereo Digital Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Delay: 4 samples
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x40f000f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1d
Node 0x20 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000034: IN OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x40f000f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x1e
Node 0x21 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70040c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x03, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x17, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00]
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x22 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x80862805
Subsystem Id: 0x80860101
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled GenLevel
  Digital category: 0x2
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560010: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=3
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560020: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=1, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=7
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560030: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono

</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

To configure PulseAudio for 7.1 channels we have two options:

#### 1) Set channels for the daemon

To set the default channels (7.1.) for the pulseaudio daemon we can edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` as root and edit the following line to

```
default-sample-channels = 8
enable-lfe-remixing = yes
```

**Note:** Pulseaudio may not run properly if not a valid channel number is given.

#### 2) Set a default card profile

We also need to define a default sound card profile in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (or if defined for a user session only in `~/.pulse/default.pa`).

```
set-card-profile <index> <name>
```

where we need to give the `<index>` of the sound card (e.g. `0`) and the `<name>`(e.g. `"Digital *** 7.1 (HDMI)"` or any other name depending on your system) of the profile we want as default. Possible values are listed with the following command

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

If there is no sink available for 8.1. sound output the sound card may not have been recognized appropriately.

---

> **Note:** for changes to settings files to take effect we need to restart the pulseaudio daemon by running
>
> `pulseaudio -k`

Comment: Setting default channels to another number is not necessary if the card is correctly recognized the different profiles will be available via pulseaudio. But unfortunately the cards is not correctly recognized. I had a similar issue recently and had to write a custom alsa config file for my card, a rather quirky workaround, but might be one step in the right direction: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sixfireusb/forums/forum/1341785/topic/5586210

Answer (score 1):

Link to a solution in Russian: [Subwoofer does not work on HP ENVY dv7](http://stafox.ru/linux-ne-rabotaet-sabvufer-na-hp-envy-dv7/)

It helped me activate subwoofer on Ubuntu 14.04. This might also work on other versions of Ubuntu as well.

Main actions:

1. Install alsa-tools-gui. In this package we need hdajackretask utility (maybe hda-jack-retask in earlier versions).
2. Choose a different codec: IDT 92HD81B1X5
3. Under the **Options** heading put a check mark in the checkbox next to where it says: *Show unconnected pins*
4. Then set *Override* for these pins:

   Pin ID: 0x0d — Internal speaker
   Pin ID: 0x0f — Internal speaker
   Pin ID: 0×10 — Internal speaker (LFE)
5. Press the **Apply now** button and enter the password.

I can't configure my audio system, but it sounds much better.

Answer (score 0):

Im posting here because the bad format on the answer to your post.

Hi Thanks for your quick response.

**Solution 1:** I've changed the channels but it only can find the 2 channels, but this make sense, because it is using my hdmi sound card and not the other.

**Solution 2:**

I believe it doesn't recognize my other sound card. It only recognizes the hdmi sound card.

Please check the output of the command 
`/home/edup# cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* |grep Codec` in my first post.

It finds out 2 soundcards. But with the command `pacmd list-sinks` it only can find the hdmi sound card.

**Question 1**
Do you have any clue to solve this question?

edup@beatsaudio:~$ pacmd list-sinks

`Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.`

> > > 1 sink(s) available.
> > >         * index: 0
> > >           name: 
> > >           driver: 
> > >           flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
> > >           state: SUSPENDED
> > >           suspend cause: IDLE 
> > >           priority: 9959
> > >           volume: 0:  72% 1:  72%
> > >                   0: -8.45 dB 1: -8.45 dB
> > >                   balance 0.00
> > >           base volume: 100%
> > >                        0.00 dB
> > >           volume steps: 65537
> > >           muted: no
> > >           current latency: 0.00 ms
> > >           max request: 0 KiB
> > >           max rewind: 0 KiB
> > >           monitor source: 0
> > >           sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
> > >           channel map: front-left,front-right
> > >                        Stereo
> > >           used by: 0
> > >           linked by: 0
> > >           configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
> > >           card: 0 
> > >           module: 4
> > >           properties:
> > >               alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
> > >               device.api = "alsa"
> > >               device.class = "sound"
> > >               alsa.class = "generic"
> > >               alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
> > >               alsa.name = "STAC92xx Analog"
> > >               alsa.id = "STAC92xx Analog"
> > >               alsa.subdevice = "0"
> > >               alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
> > >               alsa.device = "0"
> > >               alsa.card = "0"
> > >               alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
> > >               alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xc9700000 irq 55"
> > >               alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
> > >               device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
> > >               sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
> > >               device.bus = "pci"
> > >               device.vendor.id = "8086"
> > >               device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
> > >               device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
> > >               device.form_factor = "internal"
> > >               device.string = "front:0"
> > >               device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
> > >               device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
> > >               device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
> > >               device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
> > >               device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
> > >               device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
> > >               alsa.mixer_name = "Intel CougarPoint HDMI"
> > >               alsa.components = "HDA:111d7605,103c3385,00100105 HDA:80862805,80860101,00100000"
> > >               module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
> > >               device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
> > >           ports:
> > >               analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, available: unknown)
> > >                   properties:

```
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, available: no)
        properties:

active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

**Question 2**
Anyway, i tried to put the index 0 and all the names that appear (one by one) and the answer when trying to restart the pulseaudio is always the same:

`[pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to set card profile to 'HDA Intel PCH'`

output for: set-card-profile 0 HDA Intel PCH (i tried all the differente name's)

This last question is only to know what name i should put there, because this snd card is already reconized by the alsa and consequently by the pulse audio (but only with the 2 channels).

**Conclusion**
Im still not using my Digital sound card. I believe it's a problem of alsa and not pulse audio. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than writing an answer to give additional information it fits better to the design of this page to [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/131440/edit) your question to add more information if needed. By this all will stay in one place for others to be found quickly. Code or lenghty outputs can be formatted by using the `<$>` icon on top of the edit box.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct if it solved the problem